# Integrating R package with my app

Tags: javascript, r

I have to integrate R package with one of my apps. For that i have to modify the source code of it. The R package has a server file written in JS. Now what i want is that to run the server of the R package by directly from my directory. I do not want to load the package through `library()` command in R and then run the server. I am doing this so that i can manipulate the code and integrate it with my app. I tried to go inside my directory and then started R in that directory and after that when i tried to run the server command without loading it from the library, the server command didn't work. Can anybody help me in running the server directly from the source code?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at install_local, part of the devtools package . I believe it does what you want.

Wht I mean is you can modify the package, install from local location. And then load via library().
Hope this helps

Comment: But thats the point na...I have to make changes to the code so that i can integrate it in my app...if i install it then i have to make changes to the installed folder code which  will not be a good way..I have a server command which i want to use without loading it through the library command..

Comment: You download the code for the package in question to a local work directory, you then modify the package here, and install package from your working directory, and then you load it via library. you do not make modifications to the installation folder code.